# How to get X elements before and X element after a specific element with MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to generate a list of elements :

- red
- green
- **orange**
- blue
- yellow+

In that case **orange** is selected and I have the two elements before and the two elements after.

How can I get this list from a MySQL query?

An example of a table :

5 - A

---

1 - B

---

4 - C

---

8 - D

---

7 - E

---

9 - F

---

3 - G

Comment: Can you post the table structure and sample data ? the question is not clear ...

Comment: How are elements ordered in the table? Is there some ID?

Comment: Actually I wanted to generalise this. I mean, I do a SELECT request, ORDER BY a column and I give the row id and the step. And the query manage to create the rank and select the rows between the two rank-border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it with an application code :

```
def get_list_queryset(self):
    STEP = 5
    LIST_SIZE = 2*STEP+1
    current_object = self.get_object()
    query_set = list(self.model.objects.order_by(*self.model._meta.ordering))
    index = query_set.index(current_object)

    # Index too close to start
    if index < STEP:
        start_ind = 0
        end_ind = LIST_SIZE # We don't care if it's too big.
    # Index too close to end
    elif index+STEP >= len(query_set):
        end_ind = len(query_set)
        start_ind = end_ind>=LIST_SIZE and end_ind-LIST_SIZE or 0
    else:
        start_ind = index-STEP
        end_ind = start_ind+LIST_SIZE

    return query_set[start_ind:end_ind]
```

The answer is that MySQL is not good to handle that, so it is more flexible to do it in the application.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ID for each element in your base, you can do something like :

```
SELECT element FROM table 
WHERE id BETWEEN (select (id - 2) from table where element = "orange") AND (select (id + 2) from table where element = "orange")
```

Comment: This implies that Id's are sequential

Comment: Can you provide us the table structure then please ?

Answer (score 0):

It should work:

```
SELECT id, color FROM colors WHERE id = (SELECT @i:=(id - 2) 
                                         FROM colors 
                                         WHERE color = 'orange')
UNION ALL
SELECT id, color FROM colors WHERE id = @i + 1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, color FROM colors WHERE id = @i + 3
UNION ALL
SELECT id, color FROM colors WHERE id = @i + 4;
```